# C++ Client works only with localhost C# Server

Tags: c#, c++, sockets

I am working with C++ application which is windows service and C# server .
With localhost testing everything works great, but with virtualbox system or the same network computers it doesnt work.
I disabled windows firewall and antivirus.
Here is my C# Server most important code:

```
   IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2");
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 8517);
    tcpListener = new TcpListener(localEndPoint);
    tcpListener.Start();
    tcpListenerThread = new Thread(listenerSocket);
    tcpListenerThread.Start();
}

static void listenerSocket()
{
     while (true)
     {
          try
          {
              Socket client = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
              clientSockets.Add(client);
          }
          catch (Exception exc)
          {
               return;
          }
      }
}
```

And here is my C++ client most important code(according msdn examples for c++ socket clients):

```
connectToServer(){
    serviceState = DISCONNECTED;
    ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    sendbuf = "Client Service is ready";
    recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        SaveEvent(L"WSAStartup failed");    
    }
    else{       
        SaveEvent(L"WSAStartup success");           
    }
    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {      
        SaveEvent(L"Error creating socket for connecting to server");       
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else{       
        SaveEvent(L"Creating socket for connecting to server success");     
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( std::string(serverIP.begin(), serverIP.end()).c_str());
    address.sin_port = htons( serverPort ); 
    //----------------------
    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &address, sizeof(address) );
    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket (ConnectSocket);
        serviceState = DISCONNECTED;        
        SaveEvent(L"Unable to connect to server");          
        WSACleanup();
    }
    else{
        serviceState = CONNECTED;       
        SaveEvent(L"Connected to server : " + serverIP );   
        u_long iMode = 1;
        ioctlsocket(ConnectSocket, FIONBIO, &iMode);
    }
}
```

With localhost it works and i have client and server on the same ip but with different ports.
With different ips i got situation when server doesnt 'hear'  client.
My log looks like this:

```
2017-03-31 18:01:30   Settings readed: server IP = 192.168.1.2, server port = 8517-                         
2017-03-31 18:01:30   WSAStartup success        -                         
2017-03-31 18:01:30   Creating socket for connecting to server success-                         
2017-03-31 18:01:31   Unable to connect to server-
```

I would really appreciate any kind oif help i stuck with this almost one week.
I can that add ping to server ip works on client pc

Comment: Obvious question: firewalls (client and server, not just server)?

Comment: Yes i disabled on both: client and server firewall and antivirus

Comment: I'd recommend doing a tracert to that IP address to check packets are making there and then maybe run another simple server (e.g. telnet server, or something) on the port you're trying to use and check you can access it from the machine you're connecting from. If that all works then I'd revisit the code, but certainly on the C# side it looks like it should work.

Comment: I'd suggest that you call ``WSAGetLastError`` to find out what error actually occurred.

Comment: For situation i dont run server i got ERROR == 183, if i run server i got the same error ;/

Comment: John how can i check such things ?

Comment: I SOLVED ISSUE, NOW IT WORKS